# Как отсортировать точки

Tags: c#, сортировка

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было отсортировать двумерные точки. То есть объекты, у которых есть 2 числовых значения. Я хотел бы в будущем отсортировать массив из точек и использовать встроенный бинарный поиск для поиска точки. Как мне определить, меньше или больше ли точка чем та, с которой она сравнивается?

```
class Point : IComparable
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public int CompareTo(object i)
    {
        Point obj = i as Point;
        if (X == obj.X && Y == obj.Y)
            return 0;
        // Что дальше? :D
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Для чего точки сортировать? 2. По каким критериям сортировать? Если вам прямо очень сильно хочется что-нибудь посортировать, то сортируйте по квадрату расстояний от начала координат. Типо `if (X*X+Y*Y < obj.X*obj.X+obj.Y*obj.Y)`

Comment: Я же написал, что буду искать точку через встроенный бинарный поиск.

Comment: Я тоже могу абы как отсортировать. Например чисто по иксу.
Но надо чтобы работал бинарный поиск

Comment: @МаркПавлович бинарному поиску тоже без разницы что искать - это всего лишь алгоритм. Поэтому вам придется самому определиться с понятиями больше-меньше для точек. Их можно сортировать по расстоянию от центра координат, по углу поворота вектора, по расположению на осях, да по чему угодно на самом деле. И бинарному поиску также будет нужно объяснить как сравнивать ваши точки. "Стандартных" решений тут нет и быть не может. Есть обобщенные реализации алгоритмов, которым можно задать правила сравнения объектов, не более.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и не понял что конкретно вам нужно, но, как вариант, можно сравнить по X, если равны - сравнить по Y. В таком варианте равными будут только точки с совпадающими координатами. Компарер можно изменить например так:

```
public int CompareTo(object i)
{
    Point obj = i as Point;
    if (X == obj.X)
        return Y - obj.Y;
    else
        return X - obj.X;
}
```

Comment: Я решил оптимизировать игру, у меня просто в ней есть 150-200 бомб. И каждый раз в игровом цикле проверяется, наступил ли игрок на бомбу. Так вот чтобы быстрее проверять (не 200 итераций, а 7 вызовов функции - то есть может где-то 20-30), я хотел сделать красивый компаратор, который бы отсортировал + давал возможность искать.
Вот что я спрашивал.
Спасибо!